# Array filter function

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me out with this code? Apparently, I just figured out that one can't run a for loop within a filter function. How can I check all the items in array "a" in the filter function?

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  var a = [];
  for (var i = 1;i < arguments.length;i++){
    a.push(arguments[i]);
  }
  return arr.filter(function(x){ 
    for (var b = 0;b <a.length;b++) { if (x !== a[b]){return x;} }
  });
}
```

Comment: *" one can't run a for loop within a filter function"* That's an incorrect assumption. `.filter` has to either return `true` or `false`, **not** the element that should be in the result array. Have a look at the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. What exactly is the function supposed to do? What's the expected output for which input?

Comment: Ok, the function is supposed to return members of arr that are not in array "a".

Comment: Then the logic in your filter is wrong. With minimal changes it should be `for(...) { if (x === a[b]) { return false; } }; return true;`. `if (x !== a[b]){return x;}` is wrong in two ways: It returns the element instead of `true` or `false`. And assuming you mean that `x` should be included, this would include `x` if *any one* element in `a` is different from `x`. E.g. if you had `f([1,2,3], 1,2,3)` it would return `[1,2,3]`, since `1` is different from `2`, `2` is different from `1` and `3` is different from `1`.

Comment: `Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};`http://stackoverflow.com/a/4026828/1214902

Answer (score 0):

Array `filter` methods take a callback function definition which is returns `true` or `false`. `true` will include the item in the resulting array. `false` will exclude it.

Here is an example of how to use `.filter()`:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,'a','b','c','d'];

var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(item, index) {
    return typeof item === 'string' && index < 6;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

You can refer to variables outside the scope of the filter function as well:

```js
var arr1 = [2,4,6,8];
var arr2 = [5,6,7,8];

var filteredArr = arr1.filter(function(item) {
    return arr2.indexOf(item) > -1;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```